# Correct way of using Axios paramsSerializer in its version 1.x

Tags: javascript, axios

Axios has recently done a major upgrade and starting by its version 1.x I am unable to correctly introduce my own parameter serializer to it.

I used to do it as follows:

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = params => qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'comma', encode: false });
```

Now the definition of **paramsSerializer** is changed to the following:

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = {
    indexes: null,
    encode: ...
}
```

Does anyone know how I can assign my serializer to it considering the new definition?

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue, and this comment helps me a lot
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5058#issuecomment-1272107602

Hope you find it useful

Comment: Thanks but my issue is that there is no native equivalent for arrayFormat: "comma" in the new axios package.